# Ayuda con variable js, como contar la cantidad repetida de una variable sin usar listas

Tags: javascript, variables

estoy recien aprendiendo, tengo problemas al seguir avanzando, como puedo hacer para que document.write me escriba por ejemplo: "Se han registrado 2 gatos, 2 perros, para que cuente los valores que se ingresan en la variable raza"

```js
var cantidad = prompt("Cantidad de pacientes a procesar por favor?")
var cantpacientes = parseInt(cantidad)
var suma = 0
for (var i = 0; i < cantpacientes; i++){
  var numeropaciente = i+1
  var raza = prompt( "Especie paciente " + numeropaciente + " por favor");
  }
```

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que quieres, pero por otro lado, declara la variable numeroPaciente y raza, fuera del loop, para poder accederlas desde afuera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías crear un objeto en donde las especies ingresadas serian las propiedades y el valor de estas la cantidad de veces ingresada.

#### Ejemplo

```js
var cantidad = prompt("Cantidad de pacientes a procesar por favor?");
var cantpacientes = parseInt(cantidad);
var suma = 0;
// Hash de especies
var especies = {};
for (var i = 0; i < cantpacientes; i++) {
  var numeropaciente = i + 1
  var especie = prompt("Especie paciente " + numeropaciente + " por favor");
  // Si la especie aun no esta en el objeto
  if (especies[especie] === undefined) {
    especies[especie] = 0;
  }
  // Incrementamos el contador
  especies[especie]++;
}
// Generamos un arreglo con el resultado por especie
var resumen = Object.keys(especies).map(function(especie) {
  return especies[especie] + ' ' + especie;
});

document.write("Se han registrado " + resumen.join(', ') + ", para que cuente los valores que se ingresan en la variable raza");
```

Comment: Hola Marco!! Muchas gracias!! Era exacto lo que necesitaba! Me queda muy clara tu explicación!